# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un registro de una BDD en java?

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos hecha en mysql, realizé la conexión a java y lo que busco ahora es que los registros que tengo en proveedor, el atributo "Total" de cada registro de un proveedor en concreto se sume, dandome así el total del proveedor que seleccioné.
Al momento de hacer la consulta la hago de la siguiente manera.

```
 try {
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(total)total FROM " + iCaptu);
            
            
            
            System.out.println(st.executeQuery(iCaptu));
            while (rs.next()) {
                String[] datos = new String[0];
                datos[0] = rs.getString("total");

                modelo.addRow(datos);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Fallo query total = " + ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encontraron totales", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        };
```

Tambien he intentado este otro

```
 try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT SUM(total)total FROM " + iCaptu + "";
            System.out.println(query);
            st.execute(query);
            
            lblTotal.setText(query);
            

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NuevoProveedor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Sin embargo, cuando decido correr el código, salta este error:

> Fallo query total = java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets.

He intentado buscar algún tipo de documentacion de mysql en java pero actualmente no he encontrado, si alguien conoce algún manual o algún documento al respecto, me ayudaria mucho. Gracias.

Comment: Qué pasa si le añades un espacio entre los paréntesis y el alias `SELECT SUM(total) total FROM` ?

Comment: Alfabravo, Ya lo he intentado y sucede lo mismo :(

Comment: Prueba ejecutándolo sólo una vez en el primer bloque de código. Ese sysout con la segunda ejecución, que no se  asigna a nadie, suena a una mala idea.

Comment: el query es ``select sum(nombre_columna) from nombre_Tabla where condicion_columna``

Comment: Joshin. El WHERE es utilizado para usar una condicion, en este caso yo no lo usé porque necesito sumar TODOS los numero de la columna "total". De igual manera acabo de probar el query que me recomendaste en mysql y obtengo el mismo resultado que con el otro query.

Comment: Con el enunciado ``el atributo "Total" de cada registro de un proveedor en concreto se sume`` supuse que tienes una tabla Proveedor en cual tienes todos los proveedores y necesitas filtrar la suma de un proveedor en particular por ello el uso del Where. Cuando se hace un ``select`` a la base datos se usa ``executeQuery`` como en tu primer ejemplo el cuál parece que no hay ningún error, yo prefiero usar PrepareStatement, puede revisar el siguiente [enlace](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/jdbc-prepared-statement-y-su-manejo/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve investigando dentro de la documentación de Oracle, algún otro método donde pueda extraer el total y guardarlo en una variable y me encontré con el método ResultSet y utilicé este mismo para ejecutar el Statement y al fin pude obtener el total y guardarlo en una variable dentro del código.
Lo hice de la siguiente manera.
Primero cree el query con prepareStatement. (iCheque es lo que me ayuda a identificar el registro seleccionado) y luego lo "metí" dentro del resultset

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select sum(total) FROM " + "`" + iCheque + "`");
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

Después ejecuté el .next para recorrer la fila del query escrito y después cree la variable donde lo voy a guardar y obtuve el valor con el getString(1) y después lo convertí a double para ser más exactos.

```
result.next();
String sum = result.getString(1);
sumaTotal = Double.parseDouble(sum);
```

Yo hice un método para la suma del total, así que en resumen quedaría así.

```
  public double totalSuma(String iCheque) {
        try {
            java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select sum(total) FROM " + "`" + iCheque + "`");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            result.next();
            String sum = result.getString(1);
            sumaTotal = Double.parseDouble(sum);
            lblTotal.setText(sum);

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(" Error en totalSuma " + exc.getMessage());
        }
        return sumaTotal;
    }
```